# How to set 'background-size' with double cover?

Tags: css

I want to set a `background-size` with double cover like:

```
background-size:cover*200%; // not working
background-size:calc(cover*200%);  // not working
background-size:calc(cover); // not working
```

Is it possible to do it?

*I don't want to do it with javascript. thanks a lot.*

Comment: it depends on the image ratio and the dimension of the container, can you share the image? ... basically you have two cases either `200% auto` or `auto 200%` (or both combining media query)

Comment: the image from users upload, i don't know it is width > height or height > width

Comment: Sure this uploading doesn’t happen “manually”, but is handled by your CMS … so you should be able to read the image dimensions in your server-side code before you output them, no?

Comment: You can also try to use `zoom: 2;` or `transform: scale(2);` its a little difficult without knowing your desired result. If nothing else is on this element with your background these solutions might work for you

Comment: @Temani Afif helps me. so I've got his answer.thanks a lot.

Comment: I've got "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.". what's wrong with my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On idea is to consider another element where you apply the cover and you make this element twice bigger. You can use pseudo element for example.

*I kept the overflow to see the result:*

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:2px solid;
  margin:100px;
  position:relative;
  /* overflow:hidden;*/
  
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background:var(--img) center/cover no-repeat;
  width:200%;
  height:200%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/350?image=1069)"></div>
```

Same idea with scale:

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:2px solid;
  margin:100px;
  position:relative;
  /* overflow:hidden;*/
  
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:var(--img) center/cover no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:scale(2);
  
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--img:url(https://picsum.photos/200/350?image=1069)"></div>
```

Comment: with transform to do it?I'll try it

Comment: @Carson transform is simply used to center the element in this case. But you can also use scale (edited the answer)

Comment: good ideas,scale is good for me.but scale will also works for the son doms.If there is no better answer,I'll got yours answer.I've already vote up your's answer

Comment: for the first case, I've got yours answer

Comment: @Carson yes that's why I applied scale on a pseudo element and not the element .. by the way you can still apply the invert scale on child element `scale(1/2)`

Answer (score -2):

Could you try it, maybe it works
background-size: 100vw 100vh;